# How to handle objects with NULL values using case_when?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to handle NULL values using case_when, so that a value is returned when the value is null, otherwise, the object is returned as-is

```
h <- NULL
dplyr::case_when(
  is_empty(h) ~ "This is null",
  T ~ h)

> Error in value[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I don't understand why the error: shouldn't the `case_when` just output "This is null" and stop there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?case_when`

> A vector of length 1 or n, matching the length of the logical input or output vectors, with the type (and attributes) of the first RHS. **Inconsistent lengths or types will generate an error.**

Here `NULL` doesn't have any `length`

```
> length(NULL)
[1] 0
```

Thus, it will result in **inconsistent lengths** (1 vs 0).  By default, the `TRUE` in `case_when` returns `NA` (and it will be based on the value type return of other expressions i.e. here it would be `NA_character_`).  So, we may simply use the `case_when` without a `TRUE` condition

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(rlang)
> h <- NULL
> case_when(is_empty(h) ~ "This is null")
[1] "This is null"
> h <- "hello"
> case_when(is_empty(h) ~ "This is null")
[1] NA
```